# Angular filter weird error even after the functionality works

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I have an d angular django app where i am using a span to call a custom made filter from my javascript. This is my html span:

```
<span class="badge badge-success" ng-bind="mpttdetails | filter:{category.id:{{node.id}}} | sumCompletedCredits"></span>
```

This is how i defined my filter:

```
app.filter('sumCompletedCredits', function () {
            return function (mpttdetails) {
                var sum = 0;
                mpttdetails.forEach(function (detail) {
                    sum += detail.student_academic_credit.credit;
                });
                return sum;
            };
        });
```

This filter is working well and gives the desired results. But when i check the console it is throwing me an error as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined
    at Scope.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/app.js:116:23)
    at fnInvoke (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:10011:21)
    at OPERATORS.| (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:9526:59)
    at extend.constant (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:9956:14)
    at Scope.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:11949:28)
    at Object.watchExpression (<anonymous>:763:37)
    at Scope.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:11794:40)
    at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:12055:24)
    at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30) angular.js:9413
(anonymous function) angular.js:9413
(anonymous function) angular.js:6832
Scope.$digest angular.js:11821
$delegate.__proto__.$digest VM1409:844
Scope.$apply angular.js:12055
$delegate.__proto__.$apply VM1409:855
done angular.js:7837
completeRequest angular.js:8020
xhr.onreadystatechange
```

EDIT:

This is how i get my mpttdetails from a service:

```
app.controller('mycontroller', function(MpttService, $scope, $modal, $log, $http) {
    MpttService.getMptt(function(data){
        $scope.mpttdetails = data;
        console.log(data);
        });
```

What might be happening?

Comment: mpttdetails may not always be populated perhaps?

Comment: Post the part of your controller where you set mpttdetails.

Comment: hi i added the mpttdetails json which i am getting from a service.

Comment: The json you get from the server won't help to solve your problem. Post the controller where you set mpttdetails, please.

Comment: is that what you asked? here my getMptt() fetches the http url from the service.

Comment: you are using callbacks to init your mpttdetails. So mpttdetails is undefined at first call and later updated with the data. you can do what Ruben Nagoga suggests or simply put $scope.mttdetails = [] outside MpttService ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are loading value of `mpttdetails`. So at first call of filter it is `undefined`.

Add check for `undefined` in your filter implementation.

Comment: Please don't do the undefined hell stuff when working with arrays. Simply pass an empty array and your fine. No checking for undefined needed.

Comment: is `if(typeof arr === 'undefined') return;` undefined hell? It is not so difficult and will save your time if you forget to define empty array on scope.

Answer (score 0):

as @bekite mentioned, rather than checking if `$scope.mpttdetails` is `undefined` simply put `$scope.mpttdetails = []` inside your controller, this way forEach will see an empty list rather than an undefined variable.